# how to update values into database on submit?

Tags: php, mysql

I am tring to do a script for update user info from database. For this I have used textboxex to fetch userinfo from db for any userID entered and to edit the same to update. My code is

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
ENTER USER ID TO UPDATE DATA:<br/>
<input type="text" name="userid" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['userid']))echo $_POST['userid'];?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find Details"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $userID=$_POST['userid'];
    if(!$userID){
    echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the details.')</script>";
    exit(0);
    }
        global $conn; // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','root','test');// Check connection
        if (!$conn){
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }   
        $query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID='$userID'";
        $result=$conn->query($query);
        $row=$result->fetch_array();
        if($row!=null){
        $id=$row['ID'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $username=$row['username'];
        $type=$row['type']; 
        //$action=echo "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);";
        echo "<div id='item'>";
        echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
        echo"Existing Data is as:<br><br>";
        echo "User ID:<input type='text' name='idval' value='$id' wrap='physical'><br><br>";
        echo "Name:<input type='text' name='nameval' value='$name' wrap='physical'><br><br>";
        echo "User Name:<input type='text' name='userval' value='$username' wrap='physical'><br><br>";
        echo "User Type:<input type='text' name='typeval' value='$type' wrap='physical'><br><br>";
       // echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value='UPDATE'>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "</div>";
}?>
```

This is working fine and as expected. Now what I want is that as soon as when I hit that update button values changed/edited/updated values should be get updated and then displayed back to user. I have my update query and it is working fine on DB when tested. How can implement the same in php?

Comment: use a POST/Redirect/GET concept

Comment: ^ that, or use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect again to the URL you are using to get reflected changes, OR put your update query before select query so you can get updated value in select query.